# Converting a whole word to Ascii

Tags: vb.net, ascii

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Dim b As String
    Dim length As Integer

    length = Len(TextBox1.Text)

    For x = 1 To length
        s = TextBox1.Text
        b = s.Remove(0, 1)
        a = Asc(b)
        TextBox2.Text = a
    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

This is my code. I tried to do a loop so the whole word is translated to ASCII but it still did not work, I am trying to get it so a user enters a word into a text box (textbox1) then if they press button 2, the whole of textbox1 will be converted to ASCII, and displayed in textbox2.

I have looked online but I can not find anything,
the current issue I have is that when I press 'convert' only the first letter of the word is converted which is not what I want. This is done in vb 2008, forms. But I have also tried in console with similar code.

All help would be Great.

Comment: You're doing absolutely nothing with `x`, so i'm not sure what you're expecting.

Comment: `Asc` gives you the `Encoding.Default` character code for the first UTF-16 code unit (`char`). Instead of ASCII or Default (whatever it is), you might prefer the UTF-16 code unit value. That's what strings use since VB4. Try it with "[☺](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263a/index.htm)[](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F6B2/index.htm)".

Comment: Change the `s.Remove` statement to `b=s.Substring(x - 1, 1)` and the `TextBox2` statement to `TextBox2.Text += a.ToString()`.

Comment: Jim Hewitt, thanks it did work, now if i was to after converting them to ASCII also have a option to convert that lower case ASCII to uppercase ASCII without using the .lcase or .ucase function. ?

Comment: a = 97, A = 65 difference is 32
b = 98, B = 66  difference is 32
Do you think we have discovered a pattern?
The .Net methods are .ToUpper and .ToLower

Answer (score 3):

Try using a loop:

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Text

Dim input As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim output as new StringBuilder
for each item as string in input.ToCharArray()
    output.Append(Asc(item).ToString() + " ")
next

Console.WriteLine(output)
```

In this case:

> Input : Sunil
>   Output : 83 117 110 105 108

I added that space for clarity, you can change it to anything or remove it.